# How to enable line numbers in zen mode for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable line numbers in zen mode for VSCode ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In your `settings.json` insert the line:

```
"zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false
```

Comment: Is there a way, I can increase font size in zen mode?

Comment: @Mahendran Unsure about the font size, but you can zoom in. Check the keyboard shortcuts preferences to zoom in and out while in Zen Mode. Preferential zooming and turning on line numbers in Zen is sublime.

Comment: @Mahendran, You are able to increase your font size by pressing `ctrl +`. You can make it smaller using `ctrl -`

Answer (score 48):

HaaLeo's answer above gets the job done but it's far easier to do it through the UI.

`ctrl + ,` to bring up the Settings page, type "Zen Mode" in the search bar and disable the **"Zen Mode: Hide Line Numbers"** option.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It is simpler and requires less background knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to click your way through it.
File ==> Preferences ==> Settings
Search settings: zen
From the ~8 results, see Zen Mode: Hide Line Numbers
Uncheck to show Line Numbers