# How to set a shortcut key for toggling the display of line numbers in VSCode zen mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to set a shortcut key for toggling the display of line numbers on and off in Visual Studio Code zen mode. Any way to do that?

It's easy to toggle the display of line numbers on and off [via settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57615719/21477583) or [editing settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56276269/21477583). But since I need to do this frequently when debugging I'd like to set a shortcut key for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.setting-toggle to
make a keybing for toggling the setting

> Setting Toggle
> Easily toggle any VS code setting
> This extension lets you toggle up to 3 custom settings defined in the settings.json file.
>
> The primary setting can be toggled using the T button.
> Status bar can be use to show the 3 settings and can be clicked to toggle.
> Boolean fields will be toggled by default. However, one pair of two preset values can be toggled (string and ints).

Then you can assign a keyboard shortcut for its action, by finding it in `Ctrl-P` panel and clicking a wheel on the right side of line
[image]

Comment: That extension has no keyboard shortcut support. It only adds a mouse-clickable button that can be clicked to toggle a setting.

Comment: @rapsik any thing findable in Ctrl+P panel is keybindable, updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work. I tried to quit workspace (so that local settings.json is used instead of the workspace one) and set "toggle.setting1Title": "zenMode.hideLineNumbers". Then I managed to bind it to a shortcut key. I can even watch it changing the setting in real time in the json file as excepted. But for some reason, this doesn't have any effect on the actual display of the line numbers. If I then go to Code / Preferences / Settings and set it there, it works and it deletes the setting from the settings.json that was inserted by the extension.